# (When) do you need to get a new ID from your new state if you don't drive?

Tags: usa, paperwork, real-id

Let's say you have a driver's license from your state, and it's a REAL ID.
Now you're moving to another state, but you **won't** be driving there, and you **don't** have any vehicles registered in your name.

Generally speaking, are there any <strike>legal</strike> practical requirements (whether at the state or federal level) regarding whether/when you must get an updated ID, or can you keep using your old ID indefinitely for identification purposes?
And are there any scenarios where you *technically* don't legally need an ID from the new state, but where you'd face <strike>legal</strike> practical headaches if you stick with your old state (like, say, jury duty)?

And does this answer depend on whether your old address will still be a valid address for you?
(Say, if it's a second home/family/etc. that you might go back to occasionally.)

Comment: I would think this question would be way more fitting for [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com) than here

Comment: I’m not sure if this is on topic for Travel

Comment: I feel like people are too focused on "is there any **possible** way to legally to avoid getting carrying an ID" vs. "are there common situations where I would legally need a new ID?" To throw out some examples I can imagine (obviously there might be more I can't think of): might TSA care if my REAL ID is from a different state? Would my old state care if I change my address to a different state, but keep using their DL as an ID-only? etc.

Comment: Also helpful would be to know cases where "you *legally* don't need a new ID, but you will be asking for a potentially huge legal headache if you don't get one". One example I can imagine: what happens to things like jury duty? If you're far from the old state, presumably you'd be exempt from being summoned there (?) and yet the new state wouldn't have you in their database either, so you wouldn't get summoned there either (?)... so do you just... fall through the cracks? Or does the old state summon send you a summons in another state and then you have to reply that you don't live there? etc.

Comment: @user541686 Was under the impression that you were asking this question in the context of travel. It sounds like you are not asking a travel question; would tend to agree with the other comments that you should ask in another Stack Exchange.

Comment: @travelgasm: I'm not trying to debate statutes and precedents here, I'm just trying to figure out what kinds of practical issues I'd face migrating to a new place. I'm basically asking "if I travel to a new state to live there long term, what obstacles should I pay attention to if keeping my old DL, if I don't intend to drive?" Is that off-topic here? I feel like people ask this kind of thing all the time about moving between countries they're not familiar with... why would new states be any different?

Comment: With your comments it does seem clear that your question is not within our site's scope.

Comment: @RoryAlsop that was very helpful, thank you.

Comment: @user541686: if you register to vote, they'll use that for jury call. (Under "Motor Voter" obtaining a DL _or_ other state-ID usually gets you on voter roll unless you object, but you can still do voting separately if you try.) I _think_ if you title (real) property that also is used, although in the places I've been practically all real property an individual could own effectively requires a car, so RP&!DL doesn't happen.

Answer (score 3):

There are 50 US states with varying legal requirements, but [no US law](https://www.findlaw.com/legalblogs/law-and-life/do-you-have-to-carry-id-with-you-at-all-times/) requires a US citizen to carry ID in the United States.

In practice, even if you do not drive, you can’t get away with using your old ID indefinitely; it will expire at some point. If your driver’s license is expired, even a bouncer or bartender likely would send you away. Generally, it is more of a hassle to get a new ID card if your old one expired ages ago, as well.

Many US states ([California](https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/driver-licenses-identification-cards/identification-id-cards/) and [Texas](https://www.dps.texas.gov/section/driver-license/how-apply-texas-identification-card), for example) — perhaps all US states — do allow you to apply for an ID that is *just for identification* and that is *separate* from a driver’s license.

If you’re the type of person who travels frequently, though, would suggest that you consider a [US Passport Card](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/passports/need-passport/card.html) in addition to your US Passport. A US Passport Card can be used for identification as an alternative to an ID issued by a US state inside and outside of the US as well as for travel inside the US.

If you do not plan to drive in the future, an up-to-date US Passport Card could be more convenient for you than worrying about whether or not you have been in a place long enough to merit applying for a new state-specific ID or if your old one with your parents' address still is really valid, etc.

Comment: "inside and outside of the US": there's no guarantee that it would be accepted by anyone outside the US other than North American immigration officers (since that's what it was developed for).  Yes, you would probably be fine using it for most purposes in Europe, but (for example) it isn't technically sufficient for a police ID check in Germany or probably most other European countries.  Another advantage of the passport card is that it's valid for 10 years, longer at least than my driver's license.

Comment: @phoog This is accurate as written. A US Passport Card is a valid US identification card that definitely is suitable *as an alternative to a state-issued ID* for use anywhere where a valid US *state-issued ID* would be acceptable outside of the US. In practice, a US Passport Card is significantly *more likely* to be accepted outside of the US than a US state-issued ID.

Comment: US state issued ID, like the US passport card, is accepted outside the US (as proof of identification) only at the discretion of the person being shown the ID.  By contrast, driver's licenses are required to be accepted as proof of being licensed to drive.  The US explicitly disclaims validity of the passport card outside North America; any unilateral decision by another country to accept it is something that a traveler should verify before traveling.

Comment: @phoog True, there commonly is discretion involved regarding which identification to accept. For clarity that state-issued ID is referring to a *US state* and not state as in a *country*, I have edited "state-issued ID" to an "ID issued by a US state." Remember that the question is explicitly not about a driver's license, as well. Hope this helps.

Comment: "there commonly is discretion": in countries with formal documentary ID laws, an officer may have discretion as to whether an ID check is formal. That is, they might let you get away with a US driver's license or passport card by not invoking the ID law. If you're actually a suspect, or the officer is particularly officious, or if for any other reason the check is formal, you're out of luck. I only mention driver's licenses because there is a treaty requiring its signatories to accept them as proof of being able to drive.  The only document with similar status as proof of ID is the passport.

Comment: @phoog Thank you for the feedback. If you think something is incorrect in the answer, I'm happy to change it, just let me know what you think should be changed. This is a good faith answer to help an American who (1) does not want a driver's license and (2) is interested in travel. For someone in that category, a US Passport Card *in addition to* a US Passport should serve their needs. If an American is arrested outside of the US, you no doubt are correct that they would need their US Passport. In practice, a US Passport Card works for ID outside of the US the vast majority of the time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137158/discussion-between-travelgasm-and-phoog).

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I feel it slightly misses what I was trying to get at with the question. I wasn't trying to ask "is there any conceivable way to legally live in another state without an ID", to which I already know the answer is Yes. Rather, I was trying to figure out *when* I might hit legal hurdles if I did so. For examples: do states generally allow changing the address on your driver's license to one in a different state (if you don't plan on actually using it to drive)? If so, does the federal government (or related, like TSA) care, especially if it's a REAL ID? etc.

Comment: @user541686: "do states generally allow changing the address on your driver's license to one in a different state (if you don't plan on actually using it to drive)?": In my experience, no.  The federal government doesn't care, however, nor will anyone else other than a Washington police officer investigating you for a moving violation who develops a suspicion that you've lived in Washington for more than 30 days.  The state that issued your license might care if they find out that you've left, but in my experience they don't pay very close attention.

Answer (score 1):

OP, this is a frame challenge, or at least a criticism of the question and its title as currently phrased. As phrased: if you don't want to drive a motor vehicle, you don't need to get a new ID from your state, so the answer is "You don't."

In reality, the question assumes *sub silentio* that a US state (or the federal government) requires a US resident or citizen to obtain an ID. This assumption is not correct.

There is no state-level or federal-government level requirement that people within the borders of the US have or carry an ID. Neither the federal nor the state governments issue a mandatory ID.

All of this is different from many other countries, which do have such a requirement and do issue mandatory national or state IDs for (at least some) people within the country's borders.

In specific cases, however, many people are required to obtain or even carry a governmental ID. States (and I assume the District of Columbia as well) do issue non-drivers'-license ID cards, but no one is required to have or carry such an ID. To be sure, this set of people is smaller than the general set, but it's still a lot of people. For example (and not by way of limitation):

- Drivers of motor vehicles on public streets must have a state-issued (or federal-issued, for the District of Columbia) driver's license from that jurisdiction, and must carry that license when driving a vehicle on a public roadway. There are some exceptions in some places (e.g., very small mopeds, people from other countries or states who are recently-arrived), but have-and-carry-a-license is the general rule for people who drive motor vehicles.
- US Lawful Permanent Residents ("Green Card" holders) are required by the Immigration and Nationality Act to carry the Card "at all times."
- Satisfactory ID evidence is required to be held and presented to TSA by those departing via commercial aviation from a US airport.
- Travel documents (usually passports and visas) are required of those deparing via commercial aviation from a US airport for a non-US airport.
- ID information is required by the airline to be submitted to APIS in order to receive clearance from Customs and Border Protection that the individual is not on a "Don't Fly" list and can be issued a boarding pass.
- To check out a book from a public library, one must have a library card. To obtain a library card, the library will require ID.

This list could continue for pages: Want medical care? Look underage and want to buy a beer? Want to open a credit card or a bank account? Want to enroll in public school? *et cetera ad infinitum*

Comment: For most of those things (except driving of course) you do not need a driving license and can get a nation wide alternative rather than a state bound driving license. And in several cases you need a passport or a 'green card'.

Comment: I believe the INA requires *anyone* who's subject to the act to carry an id at any time. In fact, that's why *undocumented* immigrants are not in fact illegal - they're not subject to the INA and as such their lack of documentation is not breaking any law. Tourists, students, any other *legal* visitors or LPRs are in fact required to carry identification and evidence of their legal status with them at all times by the INA.

Comment: @littleadv Yes. Exactly why I wrote "...and not by way of limitation..."

Comment: @littleadv the INA requires certain aliens to carry with them an "alien registration receipt" if they have been issued such a receipt.  Many of the documents identified in the regulations as alien registration receipts are not identification documents (notably the I-94 form).  Someone who entered without inspection can't violate this provision of the INA, but they most certainly are subject to the INA generally, and they are violating several other of its provisions. Visitors are supposedly required to carry the I-94, but aren't actually given one.  There's no explicit requirement to carry ID.

Comment: David: "must carry that license when driving a vehicle on a public roadway": not in every state, at least not in New Hampshire.

Comment: @phoog If you define "carry" to mean only "on the driver's person," then you're right.  But Chapter 263:2, states "  263:2 "**Possession of License Required**. – Every person driving a motor vehicle shall have his driver's license upon his person or in the vehicle in some easily accessible place and shall display the same on demand of and manually surrender the same into the hands of the demanding officer for the inspection thereof." If not on the driver's person, the license must be "easily accessible." Here, I'd say that "carry" includes "in my wallet in the glovebox."

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica the next sentence, however, says "No person charged with a violation of this section shall be convicted if, within a period of 48 hours, he produces in the office of the arresting officer evidence that he held a valid driver's license which was in effect at the time of his arrest."  The colloquial way of expressing the interaction of these provisions is, in my experience, "you don't need to have your license with you when you drive; you have 48 hours to bring it to the police if they pull you over without it."

Comment: @phoog You're right...I didn't finish reading the section. The law does say the driver's supposed to have the license, but it also clearly provides an "out" if they don't.

Answer (score -3):

> Are there any legal requirements (whether at the state or federal level) regarding whether/when you must get an updated ID

Depends on the state, e.g. yes in Washington state, from RCW [46.20.021](http://app.leg.wa.gov/RCW/default.aspx?cite=46.20.021):

> New Washington residents must obtain a valid Washington driver's license **within thirty days** from the date they become residents.

Comment: That is a driving license, OP states not driving so not needing a driving license.

Comment: @Willeke is correct.  The law is poorly worded.  What it really means is that new Washington residents are allowed to drive using an out-of-state license for up to 30 days after the date they become residents.  Anyone who doesn't drive in Washington after the 30 days are up can refrain from obtaining a Washington license.

Comment: @phoog thanks, where did you read the actual meaning? Given the quote, it sounds like it's illegal (but most likely inconsequential) even without driving.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I'm sure phoog is correct. The quoted RCW section says every Washington resident must obtain a Washington driver's license with 30 days of becoming a resident. Phoog's view — mine as well — is that this is just bad drafting, as it just can't be that the Washington legislature meant that. What the legislature meant was _everyone who drives on the public streets in Washington must get a Washington licencse within 30 days of becoming a resident_.

Comment: Indeed, as @DavidSupportsMonica suggests, I didn't read it anywhere other than "between the lines" of the quoted statute. Consider the context: this section is from a law providing that "No person may drive a motor vehicle upon a highway in this state without first obtaining a valid driver's license issued to Washington residents under this chapter." Anyone who isn't interested in driving on a public street can ignore the entire law. Also common sense: what purpose would it serve to require non-drivers to get a DL? Why have non-driver IDs at all if non-drivers need a driver's license?

Comment: Why treat newly resident non-drivers differently from native-born non-drivers, who aren't required to have a driver's license?  If this were intended to apply to non-drivers, it would need to have exceptions for new residents who are too young or infirm or otherwise physically incapable of driving, as well as those who simply cannot pass the tests.  It has no such exceptions, of course, leading us to the same conclusion: it applies only to drivers.

Comment: @phoog Makes sense, I agree that the most likely conclusion is that it applies only to drivers, however it could also apply to whoever has a US driver's license. I agree it can't apply to people with no driver's license. Do you know why drivers must change their driver's license when moving to some states? I don't know and perhaps that could help rule out the second possible conclusion.

Comment: "Do you know why drivers must change their driver's license when moving to some states?": Drivers must change their licenses when they move to all states.  The idea is that every driver is supposed to be licensed by the jurisdiction where the driver resides.